# Split strings error whats wrong with it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, split

```
    //Seperate into arrays
NSString *NumberItems = [RawMessage componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
//Create the strings
NSString *number1 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:0];    
NSString *number2 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *number3 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:2];    
NSString *number4 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *number5 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:4];    
NSString *number6 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:5];
NSString *number7 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:6];    
NSString *number8 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:7];
NSString *number9 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:8];    
NSString *number10 = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:9];
NSString *message = [NumberItems objectAtIndex:10];
```

the string RawMessage contains this,

011597464952|01521545545|454545474|454545444|01521545545|454545474|454545444|01521545545|454545474|454545444|Hello world i am the message

the app just seems to jam after that ? and do i need to release NumberItems at the end and/or RawMessage

Comment: From the FAQ:

When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

componentsSeparatedByString returns an NSArray - you need to do something like this:

```
NSArray *NumberItems = [RawMessage componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The first line should be:

```
NSArray *NumberItems = [RawMessage componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```